# VNC - Server is running but I cannot connect

Tags: vnc

I am pretty new on endeavourOS, but I've been using arch for the better part of a year.

I want to connect my IPad via VNC, I used this guide/script to get a server running, but when I want to connect with any client, that is on the same network, and has the right ip and name and port specified, i get a “The port on which the computer is listening for a connection could not be contacted.” on the client, and no action on the server. When i nmap i get

PORT STATE SERVICE:
5900/tcp open vnc

and this:

30/11/2022 17:21:14 rfbProcessNewConnection: error in getnameinfo: Transport endpoint is not connected
30/11/2022 17:21:14 rfbNewClient: error in getnameinfo: Transport endpoint is not connected
30/11/2022 17:21:14 0 other clients
30/11/2022 17:21:14 webSocketsHandshake: unknown connection error
30/11/2022 17:21:14 Client gone
30/11/2022 17:21:14 Statistics events Transmit/ RawEquiv ( saved)
30/11/2022 17:21:14 TOTALS : 0 | 0/ 0 ( 0.0%)
30/11/2022 17:21:14 Statistics events Received/ RawEquiv ( saved)
30/11/2022 17:21:14 TOTALS : 0 | 0/ 0 ( 0.0%)

on the server.

Server and client are for sure on the same network and everything, because I was able to ping the client. In the firewall the port (5900) is set to allow everything, i even restarted the firewalld service (dont know if that changed anything)
thats how I opened the port in the firewall (firewall_config In the GUI → trusted → ports → 5900 tcp)

I double checked everything I said I already tried, so I don’t think I made a mistake there.

Any help is welcome!
Thanks in advance!